# Is this "modified wave equation" (with opposite signed derivatives) used?

Tags: waves, wick-rotation

This is the wave equation:
$$(\partial_t^2 - \nabla^2) \psi = 0$$

What is the following equation?
$$(\partial_t^2 + \nabla^2) \psi = 0$$
What's it like? What can you do with it? Does it show up anywhere in physics?

Comment: This seems like a list-based question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the wave equation in Euclidean space (or more simply, the Laplace equation). It shows up when you perform a transformation into Euclidean space, the Wick rotation

\begin{equation}
t \rightarrow it
\end{equation}

It is often used in quantum theory to resolve problems of convergence. While you are not guaranteed that you will find the same results once you transform it back, it works fine pretty commonly.

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen an application of the equation before, but an informal way to see what it represents is to make a change of variables: x=ix', where i is the imaginary unity. Then your equations becomes $(\partial_t^2 - \nabla^2) \psi'(x') = 0$. This is a wave equations. A simple solution is the planar wave $\exp(i(kx'-wt)=\exp(-kx) \exp(-iwt)$, which is a stationary "damped" wave. It actually grows exponentially in the negative direction and gets damped exponentially in the positive direction.